# Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview - Breaking FxCop Static Analysis

Tags: fxcop, visual-studio-2012

<s>After installing the Developer Preview our Custom FxCop rules project won't build as the following Dll's can't be found:</s>

FxCopSdk.dll & Microsoft.Cci.dll

It turns out that this is a red herring, looking at the project for the custom rules on other's machines, it doesn't build without re-referencing the aforementioned dll's correctly (so that's normal) the real problem is that our existing build is using the VS11 code analysis.

I've now removed VS11 but it's still not working!

Any ideas?

**Update:**
Since installing vs11 my build batch is defaulting to the VS11 version, this isn't happening on other who have installed the preview [and they are also using x64 windows 7]
[image: Image of BuildAll.bat using VS11 for Code Analysis]

Comment: Have checked if they're registered in the GAC? (The new installation might have removed them from there)

Comment: They're not in the GAC (C:\Windows\assembly\) and they're not on others machines either, so i'm guessing they weren't they in the first place?

Comment: I found out that I have them in the "Microsoft FxCop"-folder in programs. Is your dir empty?

Comment: @JonasStensved mine are here: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop`

Comment: Hmm. I have the "Professional" version (VS2010) so there might be a difference. I installed from accompanied the SDK Tools. Can't you just download an re-install FxCop and then move it to your new location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen problems with VS2012 interfering with VS2010 on a few machines so far it's been easy to flatten the machine and rebuild from scratch.