# Can Visual Studio 11 Beta be installed side by side with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Will the side-by-side installation of these 2 versions of Visual Studio interfere with each other if installed on the same machine?

Comment: Historically, beta editions have always peacefully coexisted with older RTM editions, so I assume the same will hold true here.

Comment: Have you tried installing them on the same machine? If you're concerned, install the beta on a separate machine (e.g. virtual machine).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview be installed side-by-side w/ Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425475/can-visual-studio-11-developer-preview-be-installed-side-by-side-w-visual-studi)

Comment: Is VS 11 beta the same as VS Dev Preview? If it is then this would be a duplicate question

Comment: This is very very dangerous if you plan to continue to develop for .net 4.0. This is because your development machine will use the .net 4.5 binaries (because .net 4.5 is an in-place upgrade). These binaries have bug fixes that will be "hidden" from you while debugging targeting .net 4.0. But when you deploy to a machine running only .net 4.0 (ie windows xp) then those bugs are not fixed for your user. See this post for more details:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c05a8c02-de67-47a9-b4ed-fd8b622a7e4a/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS11 comes with a "go live" license and you can install it side-by-side with VS2010. Be careful though since VS11 installs the .NET Framework 4.5 which is not a side-by-side install. When you install .NET Framework 4.5, it is an in-place upgrade of 4.0 which means you are replacing the 4.0 DLLs with the new 4.5 ones. There aren't supposed to be any compatability issues, but with any in-place upgrade there may be some subtle ones that pop up.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed both of them and they live with absolute peace :) VS 11 supports side by side installation with vs 2010 officially, so install it, you won't have any problem.

Also as a side note, VS 11 is in beta stage, but it's very stable. I've switched to VS 11 from the day it went public and found no bug yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed it, there was no problem. But since I uninstalled VS 11, 3.5 winforms project with images defined on form doesn't work properly any more. When loading buttons images, exception "Could not load assembly System.Drawing 4.0" is thrown. Since I mainly develop web applications and they run fine I didn't bother more with this.

Comment: This MSDN doc explains why: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know at a minimum it will break StructureMap and I've read others have compatibility issues.

Comment: Do you mean that StructureMap doesn't work in VS11? Or do you mean that StructureMap will no longer work in VS2010? The OP is asking about the latter case. I'm assuming he'll continue to use VS2010 for "production" work.

Answer (score 0):

The .net 4.5 release is an In-place upgrade.

This means that **the binaries for .net 4.0 will be REPLACED by the binaries for .net 4.5**.

Microsoft has attempted to mitigate the problems this causes by making a "Target .net 4.0" feature.  But this is very different from the targeting previous versions of .net (which have been side by side since .net 2.0).

Because it is a in-place upgrade, "Target .net 4.0" cannot really target it.  The best they can do is try to manually remove some "features".  They have done this (Scott Hanselman had a blog post covering this).

But don't let this fool you into thinking you are really using .net 4.0.  **Any bugs fixed by .net 4.5 will be fixed on your development machine and not for your users.**

So if you are developing an application "targeting .net 4.0" and you have .net 4.5 installed then you are at risk.  If you accidentally use a fixed bug, it will not break for you while debugging.

When you deploy your app to a machine running only .net 4.0 (ie windows xp) then those **bugs are not fixed for your user**.

For all intents and purposes, those fixed bugs are now "Hidden Bugs" (for developers that still need to target .net 4.0.

The best part is that it does not matter if you use VS 2010 or VS 2012.  Once .net 4.5 is installed the bugs are hidden.

See this post for more details: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c05a8c02-de67-47a9-b4ed-fd8b622a7e4a/