# Any problems installing VS2012 and VS 2010 on the same machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Visual Studio 2012 be installed side-by-side w/ Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425475/can-visual-studio-2012-be-installed-side-by-side-w-visual-studio-2010)

Before anyone jumps on me, I have read the official info that tells me I can install both versions without problems, but I'm a little cautious, and would like to hear from people who've actually done it before risking my dev machine!

I'm on Win7 Pro 64-bit, with VS2010 Pro SP1 in case it makes any difference.

I know that .NET 4.5 installs over 4.0, and the implications of that, but am wondering if there are any other issues I should know about.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on Windows Server 2008 64-bit with VS2010 SP1 and VS2012 on the same machine. I don't have any problems.

However, there are some issues you might want to know. Here you can find more detail:
[Can Visual Studio 2012 be installed side-by-side w/ Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425475/can-visual-studio-2012-be-installed-side-by-side-w-visual-studio-2010)