# C# Compiled With .Net 4.7.2 - will it work if .only Net 4.0 is on machine

Tags: .net

I have been researching to make sure that my newest version of my code will work with my customers' older machines - or more accurately do I have to insist the customer installs .Net 4.7.2.

I am finding plenty of information talking to whether .Net 4.7.2 is backward compatible but almost none telling me whether my program compiled with .Net 4.7.2 will still work with .Net 4.0 and TLS 1.0 implemented.

I think I am going to be ok but need to be more certain than just "I think" so if anyone is able to point me to referential data that would be great.

Comment: Your life will get easier if you stop trying to support code running on OSes that Microsoft themselves no longer support. As such, the question shouldn't arise.

Comment: I have my 4.7.2 code running with one client and if my query for the version of .Net installed is accurate it looks like they have .Net 4.6.0 and the code is running - based on the earlier comment it sounds as if my query for installed .Net version may be wrong.

Comment: as for not supporting older versions of Windows - I need to support my customers.  As such I am trying to make sure I know exactly what is needed on the machines before having them upgrade to the latest version.  The purpose of this is to stop requiring TLS 1.0 which our older version does require

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can C# projects that have 4.7.2 target framework version run on .net 4.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55791597/can-c-sharp-projects-that-have-4-7-2-target-framework-version-run-on-net-4-6-1)

Comment: J - that does answer my question - when I updated to use .Net 4.7.2 I did not implement any .Net 4.7.2-only features so while my change allows the customer to run with a newer version of .Net they do not need to do so for my code to work - thank you