# How <compilation targetFramework = "4.x.x" /> and <httpRuntime targetFramework = "4.y.y" /> works together?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, httpruntime

I understand all `.net 4.x.x` release versions are in place upgrade. I already read [post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/#:~:text=config.,in%20to%20the%20new%20behaviors.) and [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170567/what-do-the-targetframework-settings-mean-in-web-config-in-asp-net-mvc) but still I don’t fully understand application runtime behavior in context of below two configuration settings in my application :

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.x.x" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.y.y" />
```

I understand that setting  `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.y.y" />` is just short form and it actually expands to below settings :

```
<compilation targetFramework="" />
<machineKey compatibilityMode="" />
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="" />
```

Assuming above understanding of mine is correct, I would like to validate same and clear below doubts :

If `<compilation targetFramework />` setting is already there, then I assume it overrides the one generated because of `<httpRuntime targetFramework />`

For example, if both below settings below are present in my web.config :

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
```

Then effectively to runtime this means :

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
<machineKey compatibilityMode="" />
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="" />
```

I am finding difficult to understand what setting above tells runtime that application is compiled against `4.6.1` but wants to leverage features of .net framework installed on target machine (say `4.7.2`) OR what setting tells runtime that application does not want to leverage `4.7.2` features and would prefer to run under quirk mode.