# It is safe to upgrade from Visual Studio 2010 to 2012 a ASP. NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, migration, upgrade

I have a ASP. NET MVC 4 project (Web API) that was created in Visual Studio 2010 and for .NET 4.0

I would like to use Visual Studio 2012 so I was thinking about unistalling VS2010, install VS2012 and upgrade the project. This is theoretically possible but I am not sure if it is risky. Sometimes uninstall does not clean everything...

Does anyone tried it before? I think this should be a tipical issue but I have found very few information about.

Thanks in advance,

Ivan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had both installed on several system with no problems. I currently do development on both 2010 and 2012 projects on the same system with no issues (I also have 2005 and 2008 installed just in case I have to work on any legacy programs).

That said, there are some potential issues.

As noted in the thread you linked, which mostly covered beta and RC issues, there can be issues with certain differences between the 4.0 and 4.5 versions of the Framework. You may want to review info on these differences to make sure they don't apply to you. I haven't encountered any of these myself in WebForms, WCF and MVC projects but every project is different.

I'd also recommend compiling all projects (libraries, test projects, etc) referenced by your primary project to the same Framework level. I've done this with my projects to prevent any problems. I just created a branch for each Framework.

Speaking of branches, TFS works differently in VS2012 and VS2010. This one bit me and I had to run TFS manually in 2010 for my 2012 projects until the TFS team got things fixed up correctly on their server.

Answer (score 0):

You can have both versions of Visual Studio installed. Just make a copy of your project before you import it into 2012.

I haven't converted any MVC projects but just normal .Net web site projects and they converted just fine.

Comment: You don't have problems with both installed? I have read here that they can interfere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425475/can-visual-studio-2012-be-installed-side-by-side-w-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be faster to try out instead of waiting for answers, where you can still not be sure if it will really work for you. 
As Adam said: just leave old version of visual studio and install the new one besides the old one.

Comment: Once unistalled VS2010 and installed VS2012 if it fails it won't be easy to rollback